# how to get promo start and end date from dummy?

Tags: r, data-manipulation

I have the following dataframe with a date sequence and promotion dummy:

```
df = data.frame(date = seq(as.Date('2019-01-01'),as.Date('2019-01-10'), by =1), promotion = c(0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1))
```

Output:

```
   date           promotion
1  2019-01-01         0
2  2019-01-02         1
3  2019-01-03         1
4  2019-01-04         1
5  2019-01-05         0
6  2019-01-06         0
7  2019-01-07         1
8  2019-01-08         1
9  2019-01-09         1
10 2019-01-10         1
```

I need to create a dataframe with start and end date for each promotion.

Desired output:

```
       promo_start    promo_end
1      2019-01-02    2019-01-04
2      2019-01-07    2019-01-10
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can create a `group` which increments every time promotion is not on (not equal to 1), then keep only those rows which has `promotion == 1` and select `first` and `last` date from each group.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(group = cumsum(promotion != 1)) %>%
  filter(promotion == 1) %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarise(promo_start = first(date), 
            promo_end = last(date)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-group)


#  promo_start promo_end 
#   <date>      <date>    
#1 2019-01-02  2019-01-04
#2 2019-01-07  2019-01-10
```

Comment: Nice solution. While this is not part of my question, it may be worth noting that the dataframe must be arranged by date.

Answer (score 1):

We can do this with `data.table` using

```
library(data.table)
na.omit(setDT(df)[, {
    tmp = date[promotion == 1]
  .(promo_start = first(tmp), promo_end = last(tmp))
    }, rleid(promotion)])[, .(promo_start, promo_end)]
#   promo_start  promo_end
#1:  2019-01-02 2019-01-04
#2:  2019-01-07 2019-01-10
```

Comment: I suppose the data.table solution is faster than dplyr? I am using this in a for loop to create a large number of charts so this may be preferable

Comment: @kanimbla In general `data.table` solutions are found to be faster.  But, you can check with `microbenchmark` or `system.time` on your big dataset.  Here, the additional advantage is that the bult-in function `rleid` is used instead of doing some calculation with `cumsum` and others

Comment: Thanks for the hint!